# I want to know if it is possible to create a Java Annotation that enforces a specific Return Type?

Tags: java, annotations

I want to know if it is possible to create an `Annotation` that enforces a specific Return Type?

What I would like is a way to create an `Annotation` and use it like:

```
@MarkerAnnotationForcingStringReturnType
public String someWebflowMethod(...){
    ...
    return "someString";
}
```

Then I can have any method name I want, but it will have to return, a `String`, for example.

Comment: The only purpose I can see for what you are requesting is to disallow subclasses of String (which in this case is not possible because String is final, the only thing you can return here is a String or null)  Hmm, if you are trying to eliminate Null as a possible return value that's actually pretty valid--I believe @nonull or something like that is going to be available in Java 7 (?)

Comment: I think concerning the return _type_ you don't need an annotation since the return type is already String. However if you want to ensure the String has a special format and/or is not null you could create an Annotation, but then you need to build a framework around that evaluates that, since that is normally a runtime thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By themselves, annotations are simply metadata - that is, "comments" that are attached to bits of code and are included in the bytecode itself (possibly).

You could write a processor using [apt](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/) that would validate this at compile-time if you really wanted to.

But I find that declaring a method to return `String` is just as robust and more easily understandable by a typical Java developer.  Do you really have a good reason for doing this?  If you're worried that someone might change the return type, they might just as easily delete your annotation.  If you want to prevent someone from making these changes, a comment is arguably *more* effective than an annotation that they might remove for "being superfluous" (hey, we're talking about developers that you're expecting to invalidate base requirements here through incompetence/lack of awareness...).

Answer (score 7):

Doesn't the method signature itself enforce a specific return type?

Answer (score 4):

You could create your own annotation and then write your own [annotation processor](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html) which could enforce it.

I don't know of one built in... and frankly I'm not sure I see the point. If you're going to be vigilant enough to write the annotation, why would you not be vigilant enough to get the method return type right? Under what circumstances would you get the annotation right but the method wrong?